# Inconsistent resizing constraints between symbol and instance

Tags: sketch-app, digital

This might be a simple question but I have come across a weird inconsistency with my spacing constraints when I embed symbols into one another.

In this first `Filter` symbol the arrows stay right-aligned to the box as I want it to with the spacing essentially fixed:

[image]

However, in this second instance, where the symbol is embedded into another symbol `Form Filter`, then the right-side spacing of the arrows scales with the resize...

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to embed symbols like this? I had assumed the behavior would carry over. I've looked through the documentation and the forums but can't find anything on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Pin to Edge** properties to fix this issue.
Just select the arrow layer and make sure that your **Resizing** properties are like this:

[image: Pin to Edge]

It sets the arrow fixed size in vertical and horizontal dimensions and also the arrow will pin to the right side of its parent object.

You can find the full documentation from this link:

https://www.sketch.com/docs/layer-basics/constraints/